# How to Validate Request Body by allowing only attributes assigned in the Model of an asp.net core web api app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET CORE Web API app and placed a Model as:

```
public class SamplePayload
    { 
        public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
    }
```

then my controller looks like:

```
[ApiController]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> Add(SamplePayload samplePayload)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            //Throw Error
        }

        return  "Hello";
    }
}
```

However, the Action still accepts the payload if the Request Body had its payload like this (with additional attributes):

```
{
    "Attribute1":"Value1",
    "Attribute2":"Value2",
    "EvilAttribute":"EvilValue"
}
```

As you see, `EvilAttribute` is not a valid attribute according to the Model, but still, the controller accepts it, and `Model.IsValid` also returns `true` despite the fact that I have `[ApiController]` assigned on top of the controller.

My question is how can I do validation to check that only attributes defined in the Model need to be passed in the Request body? Doesn't ASP.NET core offer simpler handling?

**Note:**

The reason for this requirement is, Under a Vulnerability assessment done by an independent assessor, highlighted that my Endpoint

> accepts additional parameters in request body

The Assessment quoted as:

> - Test Category: Mass Assignment;
> - Test Conducted: Adding additional parameters to the requests
> - Findings: Additional parameters accepted with a request body
>
> Recommendations:
>
> - If possible, avoid using functions that automatically bind a client's input into code variables or internal objects.
> - Whitelist only the properties that should be updated by the client.
> - If applicable, explicitly dene and enforce schemas for the input data payloads.

Comment: You'd need to implement your Custom Model Binder i think. May I ask, why that is an issue? Why would you reject a message if it contains more items that you need? It's already been posted and received by the service anyway. The way model binder works is - it's go from a Model perspective and search from matching fields in request, and assigns values to related model properties.

Comment: @madoxdev thank you for response and for the  possible answer which I will look into tomorrow and revert back. Anyhow the reason for such requirement was that my API was highlighted as a risk during an Vulnerability assessment conducted.

Comment: Its alright. I imagine working with raw body in front of you. Best regards!

Comment: IMHO it's only a problem if you have fields that can be bound that the user wouldn't normally supply. eg `bool IsAdmin { get; set; }`. So I would reject that assessment, unless they can tell you which extra fields actually exist.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thank you! you reject that in the sense that you take whatever parameters/fields are required (With Model binding) and ignore the rest? If that's the case that is happening but If I could actually tell the requester that you have added an extra field which is a bad idea, that will suffice.

Comment: Your example is json, but your controller isn't marked with `[FromBody]` (wait ApiController implies FromBody?). Pretty sure that posting json is parsed with an input formatter, which *does* seem to have settings that will cause failure on extra properties. I think you can set them via either `services.Configure<JsonOptions>(o => ...)` or `Configure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(...)` ?

Answer (score 2):

I see not much benefits from rejecting the requests that have more data in it.

If that is some sort of requirement, here is what you can try:

I think you may need to implement your own `ModelBinder` as per example described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The way default model binding works - is going from Model perspective and search for matching fields in the request and assigns values to related model properties.

Once the model that is required can be constructed and passes all of it's internal constraints - it is Valid.

Comment: Probably need a custom ValueProvider to audit which supplied values are used, and which extra values could also be bound, regardless of which binder is used for each type.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this article: [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

> *Model binding tries to find values for the following kinds of targets:*
>
> - *Parameters of the controller action method that a request is routed to.*
> - *Parameters of the Razor Pages handler method that a request is routed to.*
> - *Public properties of a controller or PageModel class, if specified by attributes.*

For your scenario, if you set a break point in the Add method, you can see that the Model Binding will just find values based on the SamplePayload's properties.

[image]

So, I think there is no need to check whether the request body contains more data or not.

Comment: Hi @zhi-lv Thank you for the post. However, both answers elaborate on the fact that request items will be binded to Model attributes, but it doesn't highlight that there was an item in the request that is not in Model.

Answer (score 1):

An `[ApiController]` or a parameter marked as `[FromBody]` will be serialised in MVC via an input formatter, rather than binding from a value provider.

Working backwards from the mvc source code. It looks like you can control MVC's serialisation settings if you are using [System.Text.Json](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/MvcCoreMvcOptionsSetup.cs#L84), though I don't see a way to [reject extra values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#missingmemberhandling);

```cs
services.Configure<JsonOptions>(o =>
{
});
```

Or [newtonsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/DependencyInjection/NewtonsoftJsonMvcOptionsSetup.cs#L79), which does seem to allow rejecting extra values;

```cs
services.Configure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(o =>
{
    o.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
});
```

(I haven't tested this myself though...)

I would still push back on this "security" assessment. If you don't have any extra fields available to bind, then rejecting requests doesn't improve security. Though it may help consumers to understand if they have mis-spelled an attribute name.